# Limit of a special series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have come across a special series:
$$b_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\beta^{k}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\left(\beta\alpha\right)^{i}\right)\ln\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\left(\beta\alpha\right)^{i}\right)$$
I know the series must have a limit but I do not know how to get it. Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $|\beta|<1$ and $|\alpha\beta|<1$, then DCT is applicable, giving $$\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=\frac{-\log(1-\alpha\beta)}{(1-\beta)(1-\alpha\beta)}.$$

Comment: Yeah, I see! Thank you!!!